# Bonded mind -- one to one or one to many?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

If we have the teamwork feat "Bonded Mind", is the telepathy one-to-one or one-to-many? It says "as message", but message has a target line of "one creature/caster level" and this is a feat so presumably it doesn't have a caster level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### One to One.

From the feat in question:

> As long as you can see each other, you and an ally who also has this feat can trade nonverbal messages.

The feat is pretty explicit about you being able to trade messages with *an* ally, and says nothing about being able to communicate with *allies*.  You could presumably communicate with multiple allies with this feat by talking to one at a time, but not to all of them at once.

Comment: You may also want to mention that the messages "function as the *message* spell", which has a different meaning than casting the actual spell.